# Use a pre-computed list instead of RandomInteger

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic

I would like to replace `RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 10}]` in the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{c = 11}, 
  Grid[
    Map[Button[ToString @ #, 
               c = #, 
               Background -> Dynamic[If[Mod[#, c] == 0, Green, White]], 
               ImageSize -> {32, 32}, 
               Appearance ->  "Frameless"] &, 
      RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 10}],
      {2}], 
    Frame -> All, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
    Spacings -> {.2, .2}]]
```

with a series of lists; e.g., `Transpose @ Partition[Range @ (10*10), 10]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where exactly do you run into problems? Maybe I don't understand your question, but you can 1. just substitute the expression

```
DynamicModule[{c = 11}, 
 Grid[Map[Button[ToString@#, c = #, 
     Background -> Dynamic[If[Mod[#, c] == 0, Green, White]], 
     ImageSize -> {32, 32}, Appearance -> "Frameless"] &, 
   Transpose@Partition[Range@(10*10), 10], {2}], Frame -> All, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
  Spacings -> {.2, .2}]]
```

Or if you really want to have it *premade*, you can wrap the whole `DynamicModule` in `With` where you create your your substitute

```
With[{numbers = Transpose@Partition[Range@(10*10), 10]},
 DynamicModule[{c = 11}, 
  Grid[Map[Button[ToString@#, c = #, 
      Background -> Dynamic[If[Mod[#, c] == 0, Green, White]], 
      ImageSize -> {32, 32}, Appearance -> "Frameless"] &, 
    numbers, {2}], Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
   Spacings -> {.2, .2}]]
 ]
```

Comment: @ halirutan, many thanks - `With` really helped here :)